# Question about the remainder term of Taylor series.

Tags: real-analysis

[image: Taylor Theorem]

This picture is from the wikipidia. Is the error term $h_k(x-a)^k$ is correct?? I thought it should be $h_{k+1}(x)(x-a)^{k+1}.$ And is $h_k(x)$ in the picture represents $\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}$??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_Theorem) for a more precise formulation.
The error term can be of different forms. Another common variant is an integral error term, I'll see if I can find some links.

---

See [here](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Early%20Transcendentals/upfiles/Formulas4RemainderTaylorSeries5ET.pdf) for an integral representation.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I think I understand the kind of remainder term on your link.. What I want to understand is the Peano form of the remainder which is in the picture. I just want to be clear with the notation.